Proxmox Network Interfaces Setup for Cluster
I was curious if the experts here could give some feedback on preferred /etc/network/interfaces config for Proxmox VE 8 with 4 available NICs.  I plan to use Clustering with Corosync and Ceph.
I have separate VLANs for management, corosync, ceph, and other virtualized services.
This is the config I was thinking about, but not sure if it is even necessary to do all the breaking apart of the vlans, etc.  Plus with this setup I can ping across VLAN 2,3, and 4 on the machine itself, but can't touch that machine from other computers so there is certainly something wrong in that regard.  I thought they would all share the gateway I have setup on vmbr0.2 but it doesn't seem to be the case.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp87s0 inet manual

iface enp88s0 inet manual

iface enp2s0f0 inet manual

iface enp2s0f1 inet manual

iface wlp89s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        bridge-ports enp87s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 2

auto vmbr0.2
iface vmbr0.2 inet static
        address 192.168.2.20/24
        gateway 192.168.2.1
#Management

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge-ports enp88s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 3

auto vmbr1.3
iface vmbr1.3 inet static
        address 192.168.3.20/24
#CoroSync

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet manual
        bridge-ports enp2s0f0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 4

auto vmbr2.4
iface vmbr2.4 inet static
        address 192.168.4.20/24
#Ceph

auto vmbr3
iface vmbr3 inet manual
        bridge-ports enp2s0f1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 5-998
#Services

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*


Hello there! I'm just curious, may I ask why you want to use 0.2 instead of assigning the address directly? Also, is there any business related question you have in mind?

You need to be very conscious and aware in such network setups. Always draw diagrams for OSI layers 1, 2, 3, and since most of your complexity is with bridges and vlans, pay close attention to layer 2. In that layer, a PVE host with VMs and bridges must me represented as a (host) computer plus vlan-aware switches (one for each bridge) plus a few more computers (each VM and each container). Use ip link show to confirm your diagram. If you use PVE firewall, it would complicate the structure quite substantially; bear with it or not use it. I wouldn't be able to help without such a diagram.
